# Is there a reasonable explicit closed-form expression for this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$x=\frac1{\sqrt{y-1}}+\frac1{\sqrt{y+1}},$$ where $y>1$, the problem is to write the relationship explicitly in the form $y=f(x)$. It can be ground out by solving a quartic equation in $y$, with coefficients polynomial in $x$, but this leads to a horrible expression. The symmetry of the original form suggests that there might be a neater formula. I have looked at the substitution $y=(1+u)/(1-u)$, with $0<u<1$, which reduces the quartic to a cubic (in $u$), but I wonder whether there is a better way, perhaps involving a trigonometric substitution. Is there a known technique for this sort of problem?

Comment: Note that for this moment the bottoms looks like $\sqrt ( y-1)$ but not $\sqrt{y-1}$. I would say the suggested edit are definitely better.

Comment: @JohnMa: Not quite: It's $\surd(y-1)$, not $\sqrt(y-1)$, which I agree is wrong.

Comment: It's not quite: But it really looks like a broken one.